# strtok disappearing when returning -1

Tags: c, arrays, token, strtok

So I'm writing code to put strings into arrays and it's working perfectly, however I want it to terminate the reading of the strings when I hit a ## in the file. I'm running a loop and parsing the strings line by line. Within my string parser I put a loop to check for the ##. It's at the very end of my parser function and it goes:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(line)); i++)
{
    if ((buffer[i] == '#') && (buffer[i+1] == '#'))
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when it hits the line with the ## at the end it doesn't parse the string into my array. It seems like it's just ignoring the code before this loop.

As additional information I'm using strtok to put the tokens in positions in my char* array before this for loop.

EDIT: Here's my parseString function:

```
int parseString(char* line, char*** inString)
{
    char* buffer;
    int Token, i;

    buffer = (char*) malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buffer,line);
    (*inString) = (char**) malloc(MAX_TOKS * sizeof(char**));

    Token = 0;  
    (*inString)[Token++] = strtok(buffer, DELIMITERS);

    while ((((*inString)[token] = strtok(NULL, DELIMITERS)) != NULL) && (Token < MAX_TOKS))
        Token++;

    for(i=0; i<strlen(line); i++)
    {
        if ((buffer[i] == '#') && (buffer[i+1] == '#'))
        {
            return -1;
        }            
    }
    return Token;
}
```

Comment: Please don't call `strlen(line)` in the for loop conditional and try to format your code a little better.

Comment: Shall it not crash on buffer[i-1] if i == 0?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code? Provided its not enormous.

Comment: I just made an edit so you can see the whole code for the function.

Comment: Oh my lord. You know you can mark multiple lines of as code in a block?

Comment: I tried but it wasn't showing that on the preview, so I did it like that just to be safe. Thanks for formatting it for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are reading out of bounds on an array, because `array[-1]` is not good. Secondly, use a variable to hold the string length, as the way you do it causes the for loop to re-evaluate `strlen(line)` for each iteration.

Now, for your problem, it seems like you're putting it *before* the code that adds it to an array. If you could give us a bit more code, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

**Insufficient buffer allocation**

```
// buffer = (char*) malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char));
buffer = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);  // +1 for the \0
strcpy(buffer,line);
```

**Memory Leak**

The allocated 'buffer' may be lost.  The `*inString` array_ have a pointer to the beginning of 'buffer', allowing it to be freed in the calling routine, but that is iffy.  Suggest using first element of `*inString` to save that buffer explicitly.

**Algorithm hole**

`(*inString)[token-1] == NULL` should be asserted before `for()`.

**O(n*n) via strlen()**

Suggestion:

```
// for(i=0; i<strlen(line); i++)
int length = strlen(line); // `length` should be used in `malloc()` too.
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
```

**OP's early edit approach was almost OK**

Just needed to start indexing at 1, rather than 0.  No need to test every index `i` of `line`, but (length-1).  So `(i = 1; i<length; i++)` or `(i = 0; i<length-1; i++)`.

```
// for (i = 0; i < strlen(line)); i++) {
int length = strlen(line);
for (i = 1; i<length; i++) { // start at 1
  if ((buffer[i-1] == '#') && (buffer[i] == '#')) {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

---

For better assistance, recommend OP provide sample `line`, `line with the ## at the end`, `MAX_TOKS` and `DELIMITERS`.